# Use d3.dispatch to broadcast events between d3 components

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm currently working on creating a library of reusable d3 components and want to create an "interactive layer" component that basically creates a svg rectangle over my visualization and then broadcasts interactions with it to other components listening for those interactions ie. mouseover, mousemove, click, etc.

I've been following Mike Bostock's pattern for reusable d3 charts (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) and while I can create a dispatcher inside of each component to dispatch events internally I haven't been able to be successful in making separate components listen for another component's dispatch events. So basically I want one dispatcher for my library that all components then listen to if used.

I've done a lot of searching but haven't found an answer or even a hint as to how to do this, if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach that associates the events directly with the d3 components instead of forcing you to register every event in your global namespace.

The component that broadcasts events might look like this:

```
namespace.interactiveLayer = function() {

    dispatch = d3.dispatch('myEvent'); 

    me = function() {
        // ...
        svg.on('click', function() {
          pos = d3.mouse(this);
          dispatch.myEvent(pos);
        });
    };

    me = d3.rebind(me, dispatch, 'on')

    return me;
};
```

The component that listens for events might look like this:

```
namespace.listenerLayer = function() {

    me = function() {
        interactive = namespace.interactiveLayer();
        d3.select("body").call(interactive);
        interactive.on('myEvent', function(d) {
            alert('You clicked on ' + d);
        });
    };

    return me;
};
```

I've put up a fleshed-out [working example here](http://jsbin.com/devado/24/edit?html,js,output) .

Answer (score 1):

So I realized I could achieve this by just saving a reference to d3.dispatch under my libraries namespace and using this inside of my components to tie into each others events.

Like this.

```
namespace = {}
namespace.dispatch = d3.dispatch('mousemove');

//Interactive layer component
namespace.dispatch.mousemove(args)

//Other components listening for events
namespace.dispatch.on('mousemove', function(args){
    //do something here
})
```

Then inside my interactive layer component I dispatch the event and in another component I listen for it.

Comment: With this approach you'll need to register every event for every component across your entire namespace in a single place, which doesn't scale well for a complex application. You'll also run into name collisions if different components expose the same type of event.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and solved it using the below design principles:

1. Don't have the components talk to each other directly
2. Keep a centralized orchestrator who is responsible for creating and managing component states
3. Each component provides a contract of all the dispatch `call`s that it can make
4. The orchestrator, while creating the components, also creates the necessary dispatch, and *sets* it during the instantiation of the component.
5. The orchestrator listens to the events, and take appropriate actions as necessary (by invoking the public functions of other components)

Here's an example. This dummy "brush" component does not produce output, but you can see what's going on in the console log.

```js
// Here's my re-usable component
var myown = {};
myown.brush = function(){

  // setup private variables
  var height, dispatcher;

  function my(group){
    group.each(function(d,i){
      // here is the code for creating brush
      // note `this` is also available (in addition to d and i), for e.g.
      var b = d3.select(this);

      console.log("inside my each "+height);
      if (dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.call("test1");
      }
    });
  }

  my.move = function (group, position){
    console.log("in move function");

    group.each(function(d,i){
      // here is the code for moving the brush
      // note `this` is also available (in addition to d and i), for e.g.
      var b = d3.select(this), that = this;

      console.log("inside move each");
      console.log(typeof(position));   // note it is function

      // now call that function
      // using "apply" and "arguments"
      let pos = position.apply(that, arguments);
      console.log(pos);
      if (dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.call("test2");
      }
    })

    return my;
  }

  my.height = function(value){
    if(!arguments.length) return value;
    height = +value;
    return my;
  }

  my.dispatcher = function(value){
    if(!arguments.length) return dispatch ? true : false;
    dispatcher = value;
    return my;
  }

  return my;
};

// the orchestrator creates the dispatch, and the callers
var myDispatch = d3.dispatch("test1", "test2");

myDispatch.on("test1", function(){
  console.log("test1 has been called!!!");
  // call the public functions of other components (for e.g. similar to brush.move) here
});

myDispatch.on("test2", function(){
  console.log("and now, test2 has also been called!!!");
  // call the public functions of other components (for e.g. similar to brush.move) here
});

// Okay, now use all that nice code

var data = [
  {id: 1, mv: [100,500]},
  {id: 2, mv: [300,600]},
  {id: 3, mv: [800,1000]}
];

// orchestrator sets the dispatch created during instantiantion
var brush = myown.brush().height(90).dispatcher(myDispatch);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(0,"+i*100+")");

g.call(brush).call(brush.move, (d,i)=>d.mv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<title>Boilerplate for chaining component, and also for testing dispatch events</title>

<svg width=1500 height=1000></svg>
```

Note that if you do not set a dispatch during instantiation, i.e.

```
var brush = myown.brush().height(90); //.dispatcher(myDispatch);
```

the component would simply not make the calls, as a dispacher has not been set.